# cannot get .not() class selector to work on this

Tags: class, jquery-selectors

as you can see i am new in jquery, i am trying to do a simple effect, where you filter a gallery with menu links, i want the opacity change on hover, and on click i need hover to stop working. 
what i tried is adding a ".disabled" class on click, which it does add to my menu links,
and setting the hover function to a `.not(."disabled")` but apparently the hover is not checking class after dom ready, how can i fix this? any other pointer on how to optimize this function would help. 
thanks in advance.
Clazzid

here is my code:

```
$('#menu-item-43 a ,#menu-item-44 a, #menu-item-42 a, #menu-item-64 a').click(function() {
                $('#menu-item-43 a ,#menu-item-44 a, #menu-item-42 a, #menu-item-64 a').addClass('disabled');
            });


            $('#menu-item-42 a').click(function() {
                $('.exhibition, .prototyping').stop().animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 500);
            });
            $('#menu-item-42 a').click(function() {
                $('.design').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
            });

            $('#menu-item-43 a').click(function() {
                $('.design, .prototyping').stop().animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 500);
            });
            $('#menu-item-43 a').click(function() {
                $('.exhibition').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
            });

            $('#menu-item-44 a').click(function() {
                $('.design, .exhibition').stop().animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 500);
            });
            $('#menu-item-44 a').click(function() {
                $('.prototyping').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
            });

            $('#menu-item-64 a').click(function() {
                $('.design, .exhibition, .prototyping').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
            });  



            $('#menu-item-42 a').not('.disabled').hover(function() {
                $('.exhibition, .prototyping').stop().animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 500);
            });
            $('#menu-item-42 a').not('.disabled').hover(function() {
                $('.design').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
            });

            $('#menu-item-43 a').not('.disabled').hover(function() {
                $('.design, .prototyping').stop().animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 500);
            });
            $('#menu-item-43 a').not('.disabled').hover(function() {
                $('.exhibition').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
            });

            $('#menu-item-44 a').not('.disabled').hover(function() {
                $('.design, .exhibition').stop().animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 500);
            });
            $('#menu-item-44 a').not('.disabled').hover(function() {
                $('.prototyping').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
            });

            $('#menu-item-64 a').not('.disabled').hover(function() {
                $('.design, .exhibition, .prototyping').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do like this

```
$('#menu-item-43 a').hover(function() {
   if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled'))
      $('.exhibition').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
});
```

Comment: thanks Trinh! worked just how i need it, learnin more and more :)